# AndroidTestCase assertActivityRequiresPermission() not asserting correctly

Tags: android, testing, assertions, android-permissions

https://gist.github.com/blundell/ff2ac1d5ff0a41519c36
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html#assertActivityRequiresPermission(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html#assertActivityRequiresPermission(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

I've written a test for security permissions on Activities, however it's not doing what I expect.

I declare my activity in the manifest needs a permission.
I run the test that asserts for this permission.

Here is an example test that should pass, but doesn't:

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.blundell.myapplication">

  <application>
    <activity
      android:name=".SecondActivity"
      android:permission="perm.foo.bar" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

My test case:

```
package com.blundell.myapplication;

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {

    private static final String PACKAGE = "com.blundell.myapplication";

    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }

    public void testSecondActivityRequiresFooBarPermission() throws Exception {
        assertActivityRequiresPermission(PACKAGE, PACKAGE + ".SecondActivity", "perm.foo.bar");
    }
}
```

The stub activity:

```
package com.blundell.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
}
```

The stack trace when the test fails:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected security exception for perm.foo.bar
at android.test.AndroidTestCase.assertActivityRequiresPermission(AndroidTestCase.java:99)
at com.blundell.myapplication.ApplicationTest.testSecondActivityRequiresFooBarPermission(ApplicationTest.java:15)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

---

EDIT:

I have found with gradle you can add an AndroidManifest to your tests anyway and it will be merged:
@Manish Mulimani I added the instrumentation tag, but this has not made the test pass. (adding an IntentFilter & it does).

i.e.

in `/src/androidTest/AndroidManifext.xml` :

```
   <instrumentation
    android:label="new label to prove tools:replace works"
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.blundell.myapplication.test"
    tools:replace="targetPackage, label" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding [permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) element to the manifest file, before using the permission?

Comment: Yes, doesn't make a difference :-(

Answer (score 2):

The test application and application under test run in the same process. Hence the test case passes, as the test application does not need to request permissions to launch the activity.

[image]

To test the permissions, the test application should be run in a different process. This can be accomplished by assigning the test package name to [android:targetPackage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/instrumentation-element.html#trgt) in the `instrumentation` element of test application's manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.blundell.myapplication.test"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>
    <instrumentation android:label="Tests for com.blundell.myapplication.test" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" android:targetPackage="com.blundell.myapplication.test" android:handleProfiling="false" android:functionalTest="false" />
</manifest>
```

Here is the [manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/GlobalSearch/+/master/tests/permission/AndroidManifest.xml) file of old android package `com.android.globalsearch`, using it the same way. Here is comment left in that manifest file:

> We are self instrumenting so the test can be run, but since this is
>   for permissions test, we are not instrumenting any app (we want to be
>   accessing it from the outside).

Note: In case you are using gradle, then you need to manually generate the test package, install and test it. Reason from [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide):

> The value of the targetPackage attribute of the instrumentation node
>   in the test application manifest is automatically filled with the
>   package name of the tested app, even if it is customized through the
>   defaultConfig and/or the Build Type objects. This is one of the reason
>   the manifest is generated automatically.

I followed these steps, to manually build and execute the test package.

1. In app/build.gradle : set applicationId to "com.blundell.myapplication.test"
2. Build the test package : `./gradlew assembleDebugTest`
3. Install the test package : `adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-test-unaligned.apk`
4. Run the test : `adb shell am instrument -w com.blundell.myapplication.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

Here is the logcat output:

```
10-28 21:06:46.749 32649 32662 I TestRunner: started: testActivityPermission(com.blundell.myapplication.ApplicationTest)
10-28 21:06:46.754   983   993 I ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.blundell.myapplication/.SecondActivity} from pid 32649
10-28 21:06:46.754   983   993 W ActivityManager: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.blundell.myapplication/.SecondActivity } from ProcessRecord{427f4f78 32649:com.blundell.myapplication.test/u0a10111} (pid=32649, uid=10111) requires perm.foo.bar
10-28 21:06:46.755 32649 32662 I TestRunner: finished: testActivityPermission(com.blundell.myapplication.ApplicationTest)
10-28 21:06:46.755 32649 32662 I TestRunner: passed: testActivityPermission(com.blundell.myapplication.ApplicationTest)
```

Comment: So with Gradle we need to find how to make it run the tests in a separate process. Because what you describe above is a hack - in that it rebuilds the project to be in a different package name but only temporarily? Do I understand correctly.

Comment: Also what you are saying is, if I want permissions tests. They need to be ran separate from other tests (because other tests will fail if they are outside the apps process).

Comment: @Blundell You need to set the `applicationId` to the test package name, so that gradle sets the `targetPackage` to test package name. This is not a correct solution, but we need to figure out whether gradle allows to override `targetPackage`.

Comment: Regarding separate test, yes you need separate test package for permissions alone. You can check [GlobalSearch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/GlobalSearch/+/master/tests) test code structure here. I'm not sure how to accomplish same using gradle.

Comment: Right, so the answer is the test needs to run in a separate process. But with gradle we don't know how to do this at moment. (Your gradle solution only works from the command line [not AndroidStudio]) Thanks I'm going to poke the Android tools team.

Comment: couldn't get your answer to work using the AndroidManifest approach :/

Comment: @Blundell Had missed the test package installation step in my answer, I've updated it now (Step 3). Did you install the test package? Also since `SecondActivity` does not have any intent filter, it can't be invoked from external process by default. So add `android:exported=true` to `activity` element in manifest.

Comment: It works now +1 that I added an IntentFilter which makes sense. So you can only test public facing security (makes sense). Annoying that it has to be in another process - this means you cannot have this style of test alongside your normal tests (that need to be in the same process).